# Creating Custom Component Angular Package

Tags: angular, npm, angular13, npm-package

I am trying to create components which can be reusable in multiple teams. I created a new angular project and published it to azure devops artifacts.

I also tried to use the component in a new project. I am able to reference the common component package using version #. However I am getting "Cannot read property 'ɵmod' of undefined".

This is the first time I am creating a custom component package in angular.

Can anyone please help me understand the process or point me towards resources online for creating custom packages in Angular?

**Below are the tools & versions I am using:**

Angular Version: 13.3.0,
Visual Code,
Azure DevOps

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a solution for my company to share a set of components between two projects:

- Create a new project
- Implement a library in it
- Build, export and share the library as a your-library.tgz file
- Whenever you need install it: npm i assests/your-library.tgz

here is a good demo: https://indepth.dev/posts/1193/create-your-standalone-angular-library-in-10-minutes